# Facebook redirects to index page on s3 website with backbone routes

Tags: facebook-graph-api, backbone.js, amazon-s3

We have a static website on AWS S3. We have used backbone for routing.
When we tell [Facebook to crawl](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) our website eg www.example.com/#/page/destination it crawls the index page, probably because the crawler does not run javascript and gets the static og tags from our page. We have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138288/facebook-og-gets-redirected-to-the-index-page-by-backbonejs-website). However since ours is a static website, we do not have server side support. Was wondering if any body has a solution to make this work on a static S3 website. Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With S3 being the Simple Storage Service - with heavy emphasis on **simple** - there isn't really a way to accomplish what you're attempting to do here.